# How to forward incoming requests to IP through VPN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, iptables, forwarding

I am working on a project that requires connecting to our clients' networks through VPN (we are sending HTTP requests and connecting to databases on their local servers).

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

I have a set of instances on AWS but I don't want to set up VPN connections on each and every one of them, in fact I'd prefer not to change them at all if possible. (Let's call these app instances.)

So what I thought I would do is set up other instances with VPN connections per client. (Let's call these vpn instances.)

The idea is that the app instances would have the DNS of a vpn instance (e.g.: myclient.vpn.myservice) and use that for all traffic through the VPN.

Example: app instance #1 sends an HTTP request to http://myclient.vpn.myservice:1234, the vpn instance receives the request, forwards it to 1.2.3.4:1234 (on the client's local network) and returns the response to app instance #1, so from the app instance's point of view it's like sending a regular HTTP request to myclient.vpn.myservice (side-note: this should also work with regular tcp and udp connections as well).

What I've tried is enabling ip forwarding and setting iptables rules on the vpn instance like so:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.4:1234
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.4:1234
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

but that does not seem to work (at least with HTTP requests).

All servers are running on Ubuntu 20.04.

I'm not sure whether the idea is all wrong or not and I don't have particularly huge experience with Ubuntu so I'm open to suggestions, the only thing that's important is that I really don't want to change the app instances.

Comment: I would love to know why 2 people think this question does not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful

Comment: Again I don't know how this question is not about general programming hardware and software but since I managed to solve it I don't care that it's closed still the answers may had been interesting to others...

Comment: I'd argue it should have been closed but has the wrong reason. It's really more suitable for [sf] (i.e. it's about server administration, not general hardware and software, and not programming)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this I can totally understand, I didn't know about server fault, next time I have a question like this I'll post it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. First of all the steps that I wrote above were working just not from the vpn instances themselves, from the app instances it did work, but these iptables rules were too permissive, they messed up the system's internal host resolution and the sudo command became very slow after applying them.

So here's what I ended up with (staying with the example in the question):

On the vpn instances:

```sh
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.4:1234
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.4:1234
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.4:1234
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p udp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.4:1234
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

where eth0 is the instance's public network interface and tun0 is the network interface attached by the vpn.

After these rules I am able to `curl http://myclient.vpn.myservice:1234` from the all instances and receive the response from the other side of the vpn.

Answer (score 1):

There is a easiest way to set up a VPN on AWS.

You can [create a VPN in your VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-connection-vpc/) (you'll also need a Customer Gateway and Virtual Private Gateway) and change your existing Route Table to route connections from your customer VPN CIDR Range to the AWS VPN resource.

With this, connections from your instances will go to the VPN without the need of VPN instance.

Comment: Oh yeah that would be a solution and I thought of that too but it's too pricey for the company that I'm working for :/

Comment: Also as far as I know AWS only supports OpenVPN at the moment and some our clients have Cisco VPN setups

Comment: OpenVPN is for client connection. For site-to-site connections, it's different.